# May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have the following in my code:
But why is this giving the Sonar error? Error is on line: `this.lastAccessTime = lastAccessTime;` The date here is already declared private.

```
public class myClass{

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "LAST_ACCESS_TIME", nullable = false)
    private Date lastAccessTime;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param userId the user id
     * @param screenName the name of screen
     * @param lastAccessTime time of last access
     */
    public userTO(String userId, String screenName, Date lastAccessTime)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.screenName = screenName;
        this.lastAccessTime = lastAccessTime;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Date` is a mutable type, the code that passed you the `Date` can continue to modify it after passing it to your function/constructor.

So, instead of just assigning the `Date` passed to you, you should instead make a copy of it to prevent this from happening:

```
       this.lastAccessTime = new Date(lastAccessTime.getTime());
```

This is covered in [Effective Java: Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) by Joshua Bloch as *Item 39: Make defensive copies when needed*.

Note that you should make this copy before doing any validation on the Date as well.
Edit: As noted below, a null check should happen before the copy to prevent a `NullPointerException`, but other validation should be done after making the copy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. When you said "make this copy when doing any validation" do you mean my getter and setter for lastAccessTime? For example my setter would be : this.lastAccessTime = lastAccessTime == null ? null : new Date(lastAccessTime.getTime());

Comment: Well, a `null` check would still have to be done first (or you'll get a `NullPointerException`), but I was thinking more of if you need to validate that the Date is before or after some other Date.  This is actually covered in the book I referenced as well.

Comment: Ok, so if im doing validations later in the code on this Date, i should make a copy of it as well

Answer (score 0):

Since `java.util.Date` is a mutable type, the code that passed you the `java.util.Date` can continue to modify it after passing it to your function/constructor.

Consider re-factoring to an immutable type i.e. `org.joda.time.DateTime`

This is covered in [Effective Java: Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683) by Joshua Bloch as *Item 15: Minimize mutability.*

Note: It looks like you're doing some ORM stuff. [jadira](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/) Can perform the mapping to joda classes for hibernate.